# nested dictionary with two keys and one value doesn't give me the proper output

Tags: python, list, dictionary, text, directory

[the format inside counts.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VPBZ.png)I have `counts.txt` files in 50 folders that each related to one sample. I have 2 columns in `counts.txt`: one is a string and the other is a number. I try to make a nested dictionary with them. I want to use the first column of `counts.txt` and folders as a key and the second column in `counts.txt` as value. Unfortunately, the list of my folders, that I want to make a loop with them, doesn't respond and give me an error!

```
data_ali = {}

samples_name=natsorted(os.listdir(path1))
for i in samples_name:    
    with open(path1+i[0:]+"/counts.txt","rt") as fin:    
        for l in fin.readlines():    
            l=l.strip().split()    
            if l[0][:4]=='ENSG':    
                gene=l[0]    
                data_ali[gene]={}       
                reads=int(l[1])    
                data_ali[gene][samples_name]=reads
print(data_ali)
```

I expect the output of my command to be like:

```
'ENSG00000120659': {
    'Sample_1-Leish_011_v2': 14,
    'Sample_2-leish_011_v3': 7,
    'Sample_3-leish_012_v2': 6,
    'Sample_4-leish_012_v3': 1,
    'Sample_5-leish_015_v2': 9,
    'Sample_6-leish_015_v3': 3,
    'Sample_7-leish_016_v2': 4,
    'Sample_8-leish_016_v3': 8,
    'Sample_9-leish_017_v2': 8,
    'Sample_10-leish_017_v3': 2,
    'Sample_11-leish_018_v2': 4,
    'Sample_12-leish_018_v3': 4,
    'Sample_13-leish_019_v2': 7,
    'Sample_14-leish_019_v3': 4,
    'Sample_15-leish_021_v2': 12,
    'Sample_16-leish_021_v3': 5,
    'Sample_17-leish_022_v2': 4,
    'Sample_18-leish_022_v3': 2,
    'Sample_19-leish_023_v2': 9,
    'Sample_20-leish_023_v3': 6,
    'Sample_21-leish_024_v2': 22,
    'Sample_22-leish_024_v3': 10,
    'Sample_23-leish026_v2': 9,
    'Sample_24-leish026_v3': 5,
    'Sample_25-leish027_v2': 4,
    'Sample_26-leish027_v3': 1,
    'Sample_27-leish028_v2': 7,
    'Sample_28-leish028_v3': 5,
    'Sample_29-leish032_v2': 8,
    'Sample_30-leish032_v3': 2
}
```

but it gives me this error:

> unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Could you, please share a sample of counts.txt. In the line `samples_name=natsorted(os.listdir(path1))`, what is `natsorted`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following lines.

You have declared

```
data_ali[gene]={}
```

which is fine. But, then you have declared the following.

```
data_ali[gene][samples_name]=reads
```

Based on your code, I am assuming `samples_name` is a list of directories. If that is the case, then you get the error `error: unhashable type: 'list'` because you can't use a list as a key for a dictionary as a list is mutable (can be modified).

To overcome this error, you can use a tuple

```
data_ali[gene][tuple(samples_name)]=reads
```

Comment: yes but i have to use the names in that list as a key , but i have no idea how to do it except this method!

Comment: You can use `tuple` instead of a list.

Comment: but this is not a solution because it gives me out put like this not the exact one that i mentioned:
'ENSG00000007923': {('Sample_1', 'Sample_1-Leish_011_v2', .... 'Sample_30-leish032_v3'): 133} just one key and value is in here not all of them

Comment: Your question was why you got an error. The reason you got an error because you were using a list for the key. If that worked, you would have gotten an output similar to what you posted in your comment above with tuple. That means, your code never worked to give you the output you desired. You can re-write your question now asking for a solution. Please, provide your source file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `samples_name` is, but I suppose you want to create a key 
for every sample:

```
data_ali = {}

samples_name=natsorted(os.listdir(path1))
for i in samples_name:    
    with open(path1+i[0:]+"/counts.txt","rt") as fin:    
        for l in fin.readlines():    
            l=l.strip().split()    
            if l[0][:4]=='ENSG':    
                gene=l[0]    
                data_ali[gene]={}       
                reads=int(l[1]) 
                data_ali[gene][i]=reads
print(data_ali)
```

Comment: i also try this code but unfortunately it just gives me a result like this: 'ENSG00000244425': {'Sample_30-leish032_v3': 0}. The problem is that it gives you one sample name(key) and a number (value). I need sample names and number to orient as I mentioned before. sample names are a folder(directory) names that counts.txt files are inside each of them with different reads(as in my code) inside them! but the gene part is the same for all of them!